# If my HP880c deskjet powers off and I power it back on: how can I get Ubuntu send the rest of the job without having to reboot Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, hp

HP deskjet 880c connected HP 110-220z desktop with up to date 14.04 Ubuntu. This usually happens if the printer fails to feed a sheet. Often the printer feed button allows a multi-page job to continue.

Too often lately, if the feed does not work the second time, the printer will shutdown. If I power it back on Ubuntu thinks it is still there, the print spooler states that it is still processing the print job, but the printer light that flashes when it is receiving data does not flash.

Shutting down and restarting Ubuntu re-initializes the printer and the job continues to print. This is a big pain when doing research and having to shut all the programs before powering down, then reopen, remember where, etc.

I was hoping to find the hplip tool box interface in hopes it would have a way of reinitializing the printer, but besides finding documentation for it and confirming that it is apparently installed I have been unable to locate and open its graphical interface.

Can't afford a new printer even at todays prices, so any help for this 70 year old brain would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-)  As its quite difficult for me to simulate a non-working printer I'm going to use you you as a guinea pig and let you try out different things. Please always report back by leaving a comment @Fabby of the outcome (working/non-working) and **check back even when the problem is gone**, so I can actually *answer your question* so that the next person around can benefit from our work as well.  :-)

Comment: First thing to try (when the printer has its problem) is: Go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart`

Comment: @Fabby Took 100 grit sand paper to the pickup rollers, improving the paper feed to the point that we have not had a re-occurrence. Not sure if unplugging the cable in the middle of a print run will reproduce the problem. Have your restart command noted. Always a dyslectic typist in search of a button but willing to learn.  Thanks.

Comment: Hah!  A lifehack solution!  :-)  Great!  I'll remember yours!!!  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby -- Well, It happened. I pasted your instructions from a libre-office document into terminal. It worked, except the print que started to print the same document a second time. The status line indicated "processing" so the file could have had an unprocessed and processed copy on disk. The next time we cancelled the print job before restarting CUPS. Used Document viewers print function, noted that there was only one document in the print que. That printed, the que showed no documents, then the printer started printing a duplicate copy. At least we didn't have to reboot the computer! Thanks

Comment: I'll convert that to an answer later then! ;-)  First to see if there are any other knights in distress in my inbox!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When facing a printer problem under Ubuntu, the first thing to try (at the moment the printer has its problem) is:

Go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```